# rendering data via url using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my system . Users Logon to the website and using a form builder they create forms. 
Once the form has been created , i dump the form html in my database . Now i have to give them a URL which they can use to call the created form on their website . 
I want a little advice on how to create the URL's using codeigniter . If the url opens in a browser , the form should come up .

Comment: "this user has accepted an answer for 0 of 7 eligible questions"; you might want to improve that

Comment: You can find the answer to that in here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: got it..i have accepted answers..would that help now?

Comment: Yes, much better. Thank you. As for your current question... You'll get better answers if you put some more effort into your question. Do some research yourself, think about what you really need and take your time to write a clear question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a random string, place it in your database and use a controller to grab the corresponding data.

So: `site.com/getmyform/H43d0apeV`  (`domain.com/controller/randomstring`)

When creating a random string you should consider a couple of factors:

- how many users will the service have?
- how long will the generated string be active for?

The more users and longer timespan the longer the string could get in order to stay unique.
I assume there's no need for the string to be as short as possible like with bit.ly-isch services.

Another thing to consider is security. The longer the string the less chance of someone (more likely something) "guessing" it.

Comment: ok thanks...i was wondering if there was an options that'd not make me want to save the url in the db

Comment: Any other way of creating something like this I can think of is passing parameters and building it "on the fly". Since this sounds like users can create fully custom forms I don't think it would work well. However, "dumping" html in your DB might not be the best option either. It can take a lot of space. Perhaps you could pass the configuration into the database. It's more work but it will keep your application more maintainable.